# How to use expo StoreReview.requestReview()

Tags: react-native, expo

I’m trying to use StoreReview from expo, to ask the user to review the app.

I’m trying to understand how the flow should look like.
I probably need some logic to ask for a review after, let’s say a month of usage.

But do I also have to keep track of the fact that the user has seen the ReviewBanner too or after I call the method `StoreReview.requestReview();` one time, the SDK will remember and not shown the review banner twice?

And... is it normal that if I lunch the `StoreReview.requestReview();` inside the simulator, I'm asked to review the expo simulator?

Comment: Have you got this working? If you did and can post working code, that would be really helpful. I'm currently following the Expo guidelines but it's not working in my (Expo managed app). Also if you made any changes to app.json. Thanks.

Comment: Did you end up tracking if the user has seen the review already? in android docs says that if user has already review the app it will prevent the notification from showing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/storereview ?

Specifically the "Usage" section which refers to the Android and iOS guidelines on how/when to challenge your user.

Expo and these guidelines suggest when is the right time to ask the question, but it is left to the app author to decide when a "significant" event has happened during a relatively restful time of app use and to track that the question isn't presented too often (i.e. wait a month.. only ask once every few weeks, etc.), so yes, you will have to keep track of that on the App.

You should also consider that a user may use the app in multiple devices and perhaps you want to develop a strategy where the store-review suggest is made per user account and not per device.

Comment: but how do I know if the user has already add a review for example?
Also, let's assume I call the function to ask for a review, we dont' exaclty know if that modal will be displayed, so I do I know if the user has seen the modal?

Comment: I think it's the developers responsibility to track whether they showed the opportunity. Whether or not they followed thru or not depends on if the module has a callback to let you know. I'm not in front of a computer but I'm sure if it does it would be a prop you could call.

Answer (score -2):

doing something like this, worked for me.

the touchableOpacity

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleReview}>
 <Text>Click Review</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and the call

```
 handleReview = async () => {
    if (StoreReview.isAvailableAsync()) {
     await StoreReview.requestReview()
     .then(function(response){
       console.log("response is",response)
      })
     .catch(e => { console.log(e) })
    }
  }
```

Comment: isAvailableAsync returns a promise, you would need to await it

Comment: This is bad advice, the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/storereview/) explicitly says to not call StoreReview.requestReview() from a button.